# Large overhead for calling python code in tensorflow eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

I am training a deep RL agent using tensorflow on a custom environment and have noticed that calling the environment.step method in my training loop is much slower than just calling it outside. 
Here is psuedo code which explains this

```
class agent():
    ........
    def train(): 
        for i in batch_size: 
            start = time.time()
            nextstate, reward, done = env.step()
            agent.timecounter += time.time - start
```

For the agent I will find that calling env.step takes up ~.5 seconds out of the ~.8 seconds wall time for a single batch. Instead of calling inside the agent training loop, if I just call the code normally, I don't see this overhead.

```
start = time.time()
for i in batch_size: 
    out = env.step()
print(time.time() - start)
```

I will find that it only takes ~.01 seconds to run the environment.step for an equivalent amount of times. What is causing this extra overhead? It's making training for me very slow.

I tried with gym's cartpole environment and it does not have this issue. My custom environment has several dictionary attributes. Is this possibly what's causing the issue? I don't see any other differences between my code and gym's cartpole.

Full code to reproduce on your machine is available at https://github.com/ronan-keane/havsim/tree/DL3 
in scripts/meng assignments/control 1/traintest.py

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question. The issue was that the input from the neural net to the custom python code was being converted to a tf.float32. This would then cause the python code to convert everything to tensor, and all the math operations in the pure python code would then be acting on newly converted tensors. This added the huge 50x overhead. 
Issue was fixed by just converting the output of the NN to a regular python float.